# Как округляются числа double до int

Tags: java

По каком принципу происходит округление?

```
double y = 1.5;
int x = (int) y;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Остается целая часть, все остальное отбрасывается(округляется к меньшему). Даже если y = 1.999999, то x все равно будет 1

Answer (score 2):

Дробная часть отбрасывается, т.е. `1.5` округляется к `1`, а `-1.5` округляется к `-1`. Если число не влезает в диапазон `int`, то округляется до ближайшей границы диапазона:

```
 100000000000d           -> Integer.MAX_VALUE
Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY -> Integer.MAX_VALUE
-100000000000d           -> Integer.MIN_VALUE
Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY -> Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

Отдельная история с `NaN` - оно приводится к `0`.